# How can I remove the revolution slider metabox

Tags: wordpress

[metabox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yt0ew.jpg)

Is there any way to hide the Slider Revolution Metabox from the WordPress Content Editor.  Ive tried using CSS which works in the inspection panel but not when css is added to the site.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find a button "Screen Options" on the top-right of the page, click on that then you'll see some checkboxes, you can uncheck the **Slider Revolution** then it will not show on the page.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your functions.

```
// Remove Revolution Slider metabox.
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', function() {
    remove_meta_box( 'slider_revolution_metabox', 'page', 'side' );
    remove_meta_box( 'slider_revolution_metabox', 'post', 'side' );
    // Add for {CustomPostType}.
    // remove_meta_box( 'slider_revolution_metabox', '{CustomPostType}', 'side' );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will remove completely the Revolution Slider metabox, just add this code to your function.php

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', function() {
    $post_types = get_post_types();
    $meta_box_name = 'slider_revolution_metabox';
    $contexts = ['normal', 'side', 'advanced'];

    array_map(function($c) use ($post_types, $meta_box_name){
        remove_meta_box( $meta_box_name, $post_types, $c );
    }, $contexts);
});
```